# Postfix ignore maximal_queue_lifetime setting

Tags: postfix-mta

I'm trying to get the Postfix keep bounced (4.x.x dsn) messages only one day in deferred queue.

My `postconf` output

```
queue_run_delay = 300s
bounce_queue_lifetime = 0
maximal_queue_lifetime = 1d
maximal_backoff_time = 4000s
minimal_backoff_time = 3600s
mail_version = 3.1.0
```

But in `mailq` output I see messages sended 5 days ago. This means Postfix uses maximal_queue_lifetime default value 5d.

This is bounce example

```
dsn=4.7.1, status=deferred (host mx2.emailsrvr.com[146.20.161.2] said: 451 4.7.1 Received too many messages from a new or untrusted IP: 95.213.176.6 (Z27/4708082) (G28) (in reply to RCPT TO command))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is your postfix version??

Comment: postfix version 3.1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please restart your postfix server after updating any parameter

```
 Systemctl restart postfix
```

Then try to run the following command

```
 postqueue -f" or "postqueue -i <queue-id>"
```

Comment: Of course I restart postfix, but that doesn't help

Comment: try with the  postqueue -f" or "postqueue -i <queue-id>"

Comment: it didn't help for messages that were already in the bounced queue, but for new bounced messages 1 day limit work correctly. i just deleted old messages. Thanks!